# Filter out DeviceID in wmic logicaldisk

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Ok, I suppose I'll start this off by saying I'm new to coding. I've been working on a batch file that does a few things. I've gotten it to do pretty much everything I want it to do. Here is my question. Is it possible to do a wmic logicaldisk query where it'll omit a specific drive?

My current attempt was to try this:

```
wmic logicaldisk Where "DeviceID neq 'C:' " get DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName
```

and of course that didn't work... Please help.

Comment: Instead of `neq` try either `!=` or `<>`.

Comment: OMFG.... Thank you. ‍♂️

Comment: Alternatively filter out unwanted lines `WMIC LogicalDisk Get DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName 2>Nul|find /V "C:"`

Answer (score 1):

My comment as an answer:

```bat
WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID !='C:'" Get DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName 2>Nul
```

Or

```bat
WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID <> 'C:'" Get DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName 2>Nul
```

*You can also use `%SystemDrive%` instead of hardcoding the drive if necessary.*

Comment: All great information. May I ask one last question? Is it possible to eliminate a drive from the list based on multiple factors? is exlude C: drive, and disk drives? I know how to eliminate them individually now, but I haven't figured out how to combine them into one list.

Comment: You could try,`WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType !='3'" Get DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName 2>Nul`, _that would eliminate local disks_.

Comment: I don’t want it to eliminate all localdiscs though. My goal was to have it remove the SD card reader, disc drive (which both show up with drivetype 5) and the c drive. I wanted the other hard drives and usb drives to be displayed. Is this a thing? Or am I just asking to much of the command?

Comment: It was an example to show you, I thought the hint on the `DriveType` property would be enough! Honestly, this is not your question, I've already answered that, how much effort are you putting into the task yourself? `WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID !='C:' And DriveType !='2'" Get DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName 2>Nul`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the ‘And’. Again, thank you. Note to self, don’t code when tired. Have a good day!